# Calling function from a different lua-file

Tags: function, module, lua, coronasdk

I have this in menu.lua

```
local db = require "databaseconnection"
...
local function onEndBtnRelease()
    local thisandthat = db.getLoggedIn()
    native.showAlert( "Corona SDK", thisandthat.." teststring", { "OK" } )
end
...
```

and this in databaseconnection.lua

```
local function getLoggedIn()
    print("Test")
    --[[...
    ]]--

    return "some data"
end
```

The only thing I want is that String (`"some data"`) from `getLoggedIn()`, but all I get is an error:

> ...\corona\menu.lua:51:attempt to call field 'getLoggedIn' (a nil value)

The outprint is never reached.
I'm working on Corona SDK and Sublime, the needed data from `isLoggedIn()` comes from a sqlite-request. How can I reach that function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One direct way to write a module is to return a table that includes the functions you need:

```
local M = {}

function M.getLoggedIn()
    print("Test")
    --...
    return "some data"
end 

return M
```

Note that the function needs to be non-`local`, or it would be private.

See [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.html) for other advanced methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make seal class

by just writing below line at top of your class(databaseconnection.lua)

```
module(..., package.seeall)
```

than call your function in main.lua it will return the same value which you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get your data in this way.

require("databaseconnection") in your menu.lua file and call the get login function.

local abc = getLoggedIn()

print (abc)